# Plunker Delete Row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I'm new to Plunker. I'm given this table, and I'm supposed to add a function that'll allow users to delete a row.

```
columnDefs: [
    { name: 'id', width: 100},                               
    { name: 'address', width: 100 },
    { name: 'street', width: 100 },
    { name: 'delete', cellTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.deleteRow(row)">Delete</button>' }`enter code here`
  ]
```

These are the columnDefs, I added the 'delete' part down there. Now, based on tutorials I've looked through, this should produce another column that has a button attached to each row, able to delete them. However, I don't see this appearing. I don't understand why this delete column isn't forming. I can see id, address, and street, but I don't see the delete column. Why might this be?

Edit:

Further experimentation with the code raises further questions. The columDefs is within a scope titled $scope.gridOptions. Within the brackets, I have the columnDefs, which is meant to provide columns to the table. However, after commenting those out, I see instead that the columns remain in the preview.

Comment: Use proper tags (you may add tag for the grid you're using if it exists), your question is not related to plunker (but you can add link if you want to give broader context). Link to tutorial may be also helpful

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here.  You made a statement about some code that you were given, and what you are expected to produce, but didn't provide a *complete* example or even mention what framework those `columnDefs` are a part of (it isn't Plunker, since that is just a code presentation website).